# What's the right form of python interpreter?

Tags: python, cgi

I just began to learn Python for not long and I tried to run a very simple python CGI script.

The html code is

```
<form action='cgi-bin/hello_get.py' method = 'post'>
Name: <input type = 'text' name = 'name'> <br/>
<input type = 'submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

and the 'hello_get.py' file is

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe 

import cig, cgitb

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

name = form.getvalue('name')


print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s </h2> % (name)"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

However, everytime I tried it on the browser, after I press Submit, the reply was the whole 'hello_get.py' file. The page just show the whole content of 'hello_get.py' file. Like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWuTp.jpg
So where did I go wrong? It should be very simple.I thought the form of the path of   python interpreter was wrong, but I have tried several ways and nothing worked.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your first print line ends with a double quote instead of a single quote.  Change it to this:

```
print 'Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n'
```

EDIT
After looking at an example online, that first line should be surrounded by double quotes, so

```
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
```

Comment: yeah……I made that mistake. but the result is still the same, the reply still shows the file.

Comment: import and cgi are misspelled also, did you change that to import cgi?

Comment: sure, I changed that too. Nothing changed.